# Selling products through affiliate an program - how to do it right?

Tags: seo, affiliate, revenue

I have 2 kind of a strange websites that has to do with health. I originally made them just to practice SEO, and since now I am an SEO guru, they get lots of traffic. The problem is that those sites only get monetized through ads, so the nice traffic I get is monetized pretty poorly.

Since the site has to do with health, I was thinking to sell some vitamins or something similar through an affiliate program.

My questions are:

- How much money should I expect to earn per lets say 10k unique visitors? Are there any statistics for sites that are health related?
- What are some of the better affiliate programs for health products?